# How to set root view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to make slide out menu. For this I have to create `UINavigationViewController` which will control`MenuViewController`(Table View) and `ProfileViewControlle`r(Content View)

I want to set `UINavigationViewController` like a `rootViewController`, for this I wrote this code in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

let nav1 = UINavigationController()
        let mainView = MainViewController(menuViewController: nil, contentViewController: nil) //ViewController = Name of your controller
        nav1.viewControllers = [mainView]
self.window?.rootViewController = nav1

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

`MainViewController` is my `UINavigationViewController`.

But here I have error

> nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UIViewController'

What I should do?

Comment: what is your MainViewController class type?

Comment: Actually its UINavigationViewController, but i import one library and now its look like class MainViewController:ENSideMenuNavigationController, ENSideMenuDelegate {

Comment: What's `let nav1 = UINavigationController()` for?

Comment: I found that one from internet when i just started this project, I forget ;(

Answer (score 1):

1. You pass `nil` here: `MainViewController(menuViewController: nil, contentViewController: nil)` instead of some view controllers. That's probably the reason it doesn't compile.
2. You embed your MainViewController instance, which is already UINavigationController, into another one UINavigationController. That looks wrong too.

Comment: The second point explain your line: MainViewController is my UINavigationViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
LoginViewController *loginController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginController"]; //or the homeController
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;`
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means you can't set menuViewController and contentViewController to `nil`, they are not optional